# Cannot prevent invalid values in tf.nn.embedding_lookup indices

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an embedding tensor:

```
phi = tf.get_variable("phi", [self.X, self.Y], 
                initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0, 0.1))
```

and a placeholder for the indices:

```
k = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
```

I have the following code which returns the embedding in case of correct values of index, and in the case of -1, returns a tensor with zeros.

```
  kappa = tf.where(tf.not_equal(k,tf.constant(-1)),
            tf.nn.embedding_lookup(phi, k,name="k_cluster_look"),
            tf.zeros([1,self.Y]))
```

Run command:

```
x = session.run(kappa, feed_dict={k:[-1]})
```

However, I receive the error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[0] = -1 is not
>   in [0, 15177)      [[Node: k_cluster_look = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32,
>   Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](phi/read, _arg_neg_item_0_0, k_cluster_look/axis)]]

I don't understand why the `where` condition doesn't prevent invalid (-1) values from being treated as indices to the embedding lookup.

*(Using the latest version of TensorFlow)*

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?